# Get status of running worker nodes at regular intervals in spring batch deployer partition handler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am using deployer partition handler for remote partitioning in spring batch. I want to get the status of each worker node at regular intervals and display it to the user. ( Like heartbeats ). Is there any approach to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what your workers are doing (simple tasklet or chunk-oriented one) and how they are reporting their progress. Typically, workers share the same job repository as the manager step that launched them, so you should be able to track their `StepExecution` updates (readCount, writeCount, etc) on that repository using the `JobExplorer` API.

If you deploy your job on Spring Cloud DataFlow, you can use the [Step execution progress endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.8.1/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-job-step-execution-progress) to track the progress of workers.

Comment: Thanks ! Also, is it possible to get the cpu and memory usage of each worker ?

Comment: Yes. You could use JMX to report such metrics or leverage micrometer's monitoring and metrics features which are used behind the scene by Spring Batch and Spring Boot. Please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/monitoring-and-metrics.html#monitoring-and-metrics and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html